# Unable to get the security token to my email id

Tags: community, security

I have reset the security token thrice. And  I waited for  1 hour , to receive the email from salesforce.
I have still not received the security token from Sales force.My org is Sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 things you should check:

1. Check to make sure that your email address is correct in your advanced user settings.

2.Check under Administer>Email Administration>Deliverability and make sure the Access Level allow emails to be sent out. Admins sometimes set this to "No Access" to prevent users from receiving emails from a test environment.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a sandbox, users email addresses are modified to prevent users receiving multiple alerts during testing.  You need to change your email address back to a real one for any emails to actually be delivered.

The following link describes other differences between sandboxes and production:  https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_implementation_tips.htm